# Can 'That" Be omitted in this sentence

Tags: that

Senator Mike Pencil announced today **that** the Florida State Senate passed legislation...

*Edit: It's a specific example that I don't see an answer for in another post.

Comment: I'd say it's inadvisable to the point of idiomatically unacceptable  rather than strictly ungrammatical here. 'The Florida State Senate passed legislation, Senator Mike Pencil announced today.' is certainly correct and would be unacceptable with a 'That'.

Comment: You may want to ask how you can simplify your writing -- maybe how to sound less pretentious. Just a thought.

Comment: ELU is aimed at linguists.